# How to perform oxidation of keto group in presence of hydroxyl group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, halides

How to perform oxidation of keto group in presence of hydroxyl group. I fear there may be halogenation at $\ce{OH}$ group. Is there a way to protect the $\ce{OH}$ group ?

Comment: Protect the hydroxyl group, e.g. as an ether. Have a look [here](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/protectivegroups/hydroxyl.shtm).